# Should I register with A record or with CNAME?

Tags: dns, ssl-certificate, azure

I have an app service and the client gave me a SSL certificate for both x.com and www.x.com.

Should I register it in the DNS as a CNAME or as an A record?

In Azure (app service) I have access to both, but I'm not sure if I add it as a CNAME, will it let me add my Certificate to it since it is not for *.x.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I register it in the DNS as a CNAME or as an A record?

CNAME record or A record all works fine, because you add ssl ceritificate for x.com and www.x.com, when you try to access x.com, will require SSL from x.com.